# How can I add spacing between points on the axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, bigdata

I have a graph with a large amount of data (x-range of 7500, y-range of 5100). Each bar on the graph is the amount of times the word is used in the text. So I want to have the word for each point on the x-axis.

My issue is how to space them.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)

ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()

plt.xticks(x, objects, fontsize=12, rotation='vertical')
plt.yticks(range(300, 5600, 300), fontsize=12)

plt.xlabel("Word", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("Usage", fontsize=16)

plt.margins(0.2)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align="center", alpha=0.5)
plt.title('Word Usage in Beloved')
plt.show()
```

Currently the code produces:

[image: This is what it looks like currently.]

Comment: you want to have 7500 (readable) words along the x-axis? That's going to be a really wide plot, no?

Comment: @tom that's a good point...I have the word/number combos stored in an OrderedDict. Is there a simple way of removing all of the items that have words less than 4 characters or uses less than say, 5?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code modified using your code. By adding the dictonary keys to xticks and the values to bar and by measuring the length of D I was able to get each word for each x axis bar.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)

ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()

D = {u'Label0':26, u'Label1': 17, u'Label2':30, u'Label3': 20, u'Label4': 12}

y = [4, 9, 2]

plt.xticks(range(len(D)), D.keys(), fontsize=12, rotation='vertical')
plt.yticks(range(300, 5600, 300), fontsize=12)

plt.xlabel("Word", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("Usage", fontsize=16)

plt.margins(0.2)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.bar(y, D.values(), align="center", alpha=0.5)
plt.title('Word Usage in Beloved')
plt.show()
```

Since the rest of your code was not posted I can only work with what I have. If you post your full code I may be able to help you out better. Hope this helps some.